# IF statements giving Cannot resolve symbol in PDFDocument

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, pdf-generation

So In my app I upload images to my company server

These Images are then converted to PDF with the built PDFdocument method,

Now my Issue is I am trying to make the PDF genertation dynamic by adding IF statements. 
So My images are loaded into a arraylist and I call a PDF page creation if there is an item in a certain position in the ArrayList with

```
 if(list.contains(list.get(0))){
code here

}
```

BUT I am getting Cannot resolve symbols on the code for the next page.

So what I want to Happen IF the list contains a item at position X  then it makes a page so the endgame is that for every image the user selects a new page will be created

**PDF Creation Code**

```
PdfDocument document=new PdfDocument();

    if(list.contains(list.get(0))) {
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 6000, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas=page.getCanvas();

        Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(0));
        canvas.setDensity(DENSITY_XHIGH);
        image.setDensity(DENSITY_XHIGH);
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, 1, 1, null);
        document.finishPage(page);
    }
```

** here I am Getting cannot resolve symbols on page, pageInfo, canvas**

```
if(list.contains(list.get(1))) {
         pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(, 6000, 2).create();
        page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        canvas = page.getCanvas();

            Bitmap image2=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list.get(1));
            canvas.setDensity(DENSITY_XHIGH);
            image2.setDensity(DENSITY_XHIGH);
            canvas.drawBitmap(image2, 1, 1, null);
            document.finishPage(page);
}


        String directory_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/mypdf/";
        File file=new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String timeStamp = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")).format(new Date());
        String targetPdf=directory_path + timeStamp +".pdf";
        File filePath=new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wrong: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close the document
        document.close();
```

I think that My problem is I have syntax error somewhere with m IF statements, but I am not sure Any help Will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-iterate

In this code

```
if(list.contains(list.get(0))) {
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo=new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 6000, 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page=document.startPage(pageInfo);
    Canvas canvas=page.getCanvas();
    ....
 }
```

you are declaring the variables `pageInfo` `page` and `canvas` - they are limited in scope to this block, so they are not visible to

```
if(list.contains(list.get(1))) {
     pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(, 6000, 2).create();
    page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
    canvas = page.getCanvas();
    ....
}
```

You can declare them before the **first** `if` block as

```
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = null;
PdfDocument.Page page = null;
Canvas canvas = null;

if(list.contains(list.get(0))) {
     pageInfo = .... // set value
}
```

and

```
if(list.contains(list.get(1))) {
     pageInfo = ....
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you that solved the issue but now i am getting Process: com.smartpractice.smartpracticesmartapp, PID: 21884
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 on my second IF statements But I will post another question for this, only problem is people are downvoting my questions for reasons I don't know

Comment: @RubenMeiring most likely because the problems you run into are very, VERY basic, yet the code you post in your questions doesn't seem that basic. Seeing as I didn't downvote your question, I can only imagine this to be the reason.

Comment: I have only been coding in Java for a month or so So alot of my code are experimentation and trial and error Thank Anyways dudes

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with your if statements, just with the scope of your code blocks.

```
if ( condition ) {
  String t = "yes";
}
System.out.println("myString " + t);
```

this simple code will cause the exact same problem as your current code. `t` is a local variable in your if block. Once that block is finished, the variable doesn't exist anymore.

To fix this:

```
String t = "";
if ( condition ) {
  t = "yes";
}
System.out.println("myString " + t);
```

This way, the `t` variable is accessible after your if block is finished, because, since it wasn't declared within the if block, it isn't limited to it's scope.

Comment: OK, got it.  Did not realize that you were giving some simple code rather than the OP's code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat wasn't planning on copy pasting it all, or re-typing it all myself :)